# How to push checked items from primeng multiselect into a local array

Tags: angular, primeng

Here is the [stackblitz.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-button-demo-52c4w3)

I'm using primeng multiselect component. I want to push selections into a `localArray`. Though there is a property `[(ngModel)]="selectedCities"` which automatically stores only those item names which are ticked. But I want to store all items that i click no matter I deselect them or just click on the name and not on the corresponding check box.

Here is my code:

```
<p-multiSelect selectionLimit=3 [(ngModel)]="selectedCities" [options]="cities" optionLabel="name"
  (click)="onClick($event)">
</p-multiSelect> 



localArray = [];

  constructor() {
    this.cities = [
      { name: 'New York', code: 'NY' },
      { name: 'Rome', code: 'RM' },
      { name: 'London', code: 'LDN' },
      { name: 'Istanbul', code: 'IST' },
      { name: 'Paris', code: 'PRS' }
    ];
  }

  onClick(e) {
    console.log(e);
    this.localArray.push(e.target.name);
  }
```

Also I'm limiting the selection limit to 3. But still the logic should be written in such a way that it should keep pushing to the `localArray` even when the limit is reached.

Please see the stackblitz for working demo. Please correct my mistake.

Comment: here its working fine https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-button-demo-vftprf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: @GaurangDhorda, No its not. Please open the console and see this error: `InternalError: too much recursion`

Comment: Actually, what you need after 3 selection of checkbox ?

Comment: @GaurangDhorda, No no. Please read the question again. I want the selections to be stored in array.

Comment: only three check list will be push to array only ?

Comment: Yes @GaurangDhorda, only latest 3 should be pushed. The logic should keep on replacing previously selected items by newly selected items.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232259/discussion-between-gaurangdhorda-and-tanzeel).

Comment: If you still face this problem, come to discussion panel. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232259/discussion-between-gaurangdhorda-and-tanzeel

Answer (score 0):

You should change (onClick) to (onChange)

HTML:

```
<p-multiSelect selectionLimit=3 [(ngModel)]="selectedCities" [options]="cities" optionLabel="name"
  (onChange)="onChange($event)">
</p-multiSelect>
```

TS:

```
 onChange(e) {
    console.log(e);
    this.localArray.push(e.itemValue.name);
    console.log(this.localArray);
  }
```

Hope, that will help you

Answer (score 0):

You should make local copy

```
onChange(e) { 
  this.localArray = [...this.selectedCities];
}
```